# umbracoNaviHide not working in Where statement

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, umbraco, umbraco5

Trying to get children of a given document type, with umbracoNavihide not set to false:

The following produces correct output.

```
@foreach (var child in root.Children.Where("ContentTypeAlias == \"DocumentTypehere\""))
{
    if (child.umbracoNaviHide == "False")
    {
        continue;
    }
    <li>@child.Name</li>
}
```

This does not:

```
@foreach (var child in root.Children.Where("umbracoNaviHide == @0 && ContentTypeAlias == \"DocumentTypehere\"","False"))
{
        <li>@child.Name</li>   
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`umbracoNaviHide` is not supported in Umbraco 5 as per [the words of Niels Hartvig](http://our.umbraco.org/forum/core/umbraco-5-general-discussion/25819-Umbraco-5-Does-umbracoUrlName,-umbracoUrlAlias,-umbracoRedirect,-umbracoNaviHide,-umbracoInternalRedirectId-still-work):

> While these special aliases does *[sic] [recte: do]* a great job and are super easy to use
>   (albeit totally impossible to discover if you don't stumble across
>   docs that mention their usage), the problem with these are that
>   they're 'magic' strings which really is a mess (read: They're hacks
>   inside the core).
>
> So they won't come back in v5 in the form we know from v4.

So, besides the Linq imitations being somewhat broken anyway, the short answer is that this (either form) shouldn't work (nor should Athul's answer).

The long answer is that you could use this property (and others like it) only if you explicitly support it as part of your Document Type. There is a feature request, though, asking for the 'built-in' `umbraco...` properties [here should you care to follow and support it](http://issues.umbraco.org/issue/U5-254).

I would personally ask that you don't, however; as using these properties and relying on them are problematic (not least for the point mentioned by Neils himself). Make your own, dedicated properties that are aptly aliased for their task.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply do it like

```
@foreach (var child in root.Children.Where("umbracoNaviHide != true &&  NodeTypeAlias == \"DocumentTypehere\" ")
{
    <li>@child.Name</li>   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just write for your check on umbracoNaviHide:

```
if (!child.umbracoNaviHide)
{
    continue;
}
<li>@child.Name</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add another approach - a few of the existing answers did not work for me - you can try this. Works for me in Umbraco 4.11

```
@foreach (var child in root.Children.Where(child => child.GetPropertyValue("umbracoNaviHide") == "0"))
{
..
}
```