# How do I enable umbracoNaviHide in Umbraco 7

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, xslt, umbraco7

I am new to Umbraco and I am trying to hide a page from the nav bar. Based on what I have read I need to change the value of the property `umbracoNaviHide`. Nothing I have read gives any specific information on how to do this or where this property would be located. I also am having a hard time finding detailed information about umbraco 7.

Is this something that I need to enable in an xslt file somewhere so that it shows up as an editable property in the Umbraco UI or do I need to add some code somewhere and rebuild umbraco?

Is this a property that I need to include in my template files somewhere?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10319943/umbraconavihide-not-working-in-where-statement ?

Comment: @NicolásCarlo, I saw this post, but I don't really understand in what context they are using this. If I could easily set this property using some embedded C# in my template, that would be great.

Comment: Wrote it as an answer. Glad it helped.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to: http://www.systenics.com/blog/create-a-responsive,-fluid-html5css3-based-website-on-umbraco-7-using-bootstrap-30-framework/?tag=Umbraco+7 and look for `umbracoNaviHide` on the page and you will see how to set this property.

Relevant text from the link:

> Switch to the Generic properties tab and click on the Click here to
>   add a new property link...

*Generic Properties tab can be found by going to `Settings->DocumentType->[Name of your document type]` and then click on Generic Properties on the right side.*

and follow the instructions provided in the following image:

[image]

This post might also be helpful to understand how an Umbraco site is setup: http://24days.in/umbraco/2014/how-to-set-up-an-umbraco-site/

Answer (score 0):

Old post, but an update for v7.4

> Related Changes
>   Summary - 7.4 beta - Option toCannot add properties to the "Generic properties" tab
>
> Description - In the 7.4 beta it's not possible anymore to add properties to the "Generic properties" tab. I know this has been done because properties can be a bit hidden on that tab and usually are better on a separate tab. But there are situations where the properties are better on that tab.

http://issues.umbraco.org/issue/U4-7699#comment=67-25502